# Unable to set environment java_home in Ant builder configuration to access in shell script

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

Unable to set environment java_home in Ant builder launch configuration.

Using ant task, i just invoked shell script "run.sh" which contains

echo ${JAVA_HOME}

while executing ant task via launch configuration. its prints empty...

For example,

In build.xml file

```
<project name="Sample">
 <target name="test">
 <exec executable="/bin/bash">
 <arg value="run.sh"/>
 </exec> 
</target>
 </project>
```

assume I have following shell script run.sh which contains JAVA_HOME, With help of it i need to do some action in sh.

Answer (score 0):

You havn't given your code snippet. Anyways write only echo $JAVA_HOME in the run.sh file.Also provide absolute path to run.sh look at below snippet.

```
<project name="Sample" default="automate">
<target name="automate">
<exec executable="/bin/bash">
<arg value="/root/test/Work/run.sh"/>
<arg value="/root/test/Work"/>
</exec>
</target>
```